# Youtrack Rest API add attachments to comment

Tags: python, rest, youtrack-api

How add attachment to issues's comment wia Rest API?

I try this:

```
encoderrrr=MultipartEncoder(fields={
        'file':('tets.jpg', open('./project/MAC/MAC-338/screenshot-1.png','rb'))
        })
auth_login,auth_password ='USER','PASSWORD'
headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
    'Content-Type': encoderrrr.content_type}
r = requests.post('https://youtrack.URL.com/api/issues/{}/attachments/{}'.format('MAC-1','4-400'),
auth=HTTPBasicAuth(auth_login,auth_password),
data= encoderrrr,
headers=headers)
print(r.text)
```

And i get error

`{"error":"Not Found","error_description":"Entity with id 4-400 not found"}`

How I can send attachment to comment?

Comment: It's close needs norlam URL '''('https://youtrack.URL.com/api/issues/{}/comments/{}/attachments'.format('MAC-1','4-400')'''